# Add multiple sort keys in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to add more than one sort key in an AWS DynamoDB table.

I tried the adding it on create table but my table is already ready and now and I have to change my table schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete the old table and create a new table if you want to use a **local secondary index**, because that has to be created at table creation time.

Alternatively you could create a **global secondary index** with the same partition key but a different sort key. This will be more expensive in terms of storage cost.

To learn more about the differences between secondary indexes, check out: [Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) in the DynamoDB Developer Guide.